# ActivityLifecycleCallbacks before api 14

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

How do people use ActivityLifecycleCallbacks for apps targeting say API 10? I need to use it to start and stop a Service. Alternatively, can I start and stop a service from the manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do people use ActivityLifecycleCallbacks for apps targeting say API 10?

They are not available. Instead, you put logic in all your activities, in their lifecycle methods, corresponding to the particular `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` methods that you were interested in.

Considering that [devices below API Level 14 make up ~5% of the Google Play ecosystem at the present time](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html), you might consider raising your `minSdkVersion` to 14 (or even 15).

> Alternatively, can I start and stop a service from the manifest?

No, sorry.